# Accessing 3d content file hosted in a protected folder via Apple Quick Loop for AR in Safari-iOS

Tags: ios, safari, augmented-reality, arquicklook

In order to keep my Quick Look AR webapp out of public ambit along its development cycle, I've opted for hosting it in a protected folder.

The point is that, although under this approach Quick Look refuses to open the 3d content (USDZ/reality file), showing instead the warning "Object could not be opened" when passing to AR view.

That said, It seems to me that, to access the file, Safari is not using here the already opened session. Isn't it?

Anyway to workaround this behaviour?

Best for your time.